# How to combine text from multiple files into one using bash?

Tags: bash

```
Example:
File (A) = Group.txt

File (B) = Name.txt

File (C) = Title.txt

File (D) = Rep_Number.txt
```

What I am trying to accomplish is, copy line one from files A, B, C and D. Once the first line has been copied from these 4 files I need them to be compiled into file E, for example:

```
File (E)

Sales | Mathew | Manager | 1022132625 
support | Robert | Employee | 5421565581 
Project man. | Jake | Employee | 5412765894
```

Just to be clear I need line #1 from files A, B, C and D to be compiled into file E line #1. Line #2 from files A, B, C and D to be compiled into file E line #2, and so on. Thanks in advanced!!

Comment: see this related question and answer (simply, the ol' cat command) [http://superuser.com/questions/228878/how-can-i-concatenate-two-files-in-unix][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/228878/how-can-i-concatenate-two-files-in-unix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not strictly bash, so perhaps it's not applicable for you, but the program *paste* can fix this for you with ease:

`paste -d " | " Group.txt Name.txt Title.txt Rep_Number.txt > Output.txt`

The delimiter is given with the -d flag, default is tab; the `> Output.txt` redirects the resulting output from standard output to a textfile.

Comment: Hey any answer is good for me, I'm still waiting on some files to build so once I get a chance I will give this a go. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear! :) I tested it by creating three files as per your question, so the output should be satisfactory. Forgot to mention that the original answer writes to stdout, so you'll want to redirect the output to your file E.